# How to dump all transaction from single bitcoin address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, blockchain.info, bitcoin-core-development

How to get/dump/or download/curl request/ for all transaction from single address ??? I need info about txID's, scryptpubkeys, txinwitness and other deep info about transactions

Br.

Comment: What have you tried? What part of them job is causing most trouble?

Comment: Hello. I need dupm TXiD, ScriptPubkey, txinwitness FOR ALL Transactions. Manually dump 5000 transaction is hard, because blockchain.com give only 50 transactions per once request.

Comment: Have you tried submitting multiple requests?

Comment: blockchain,com not worked for me - json without txinwitness !!!

Comment: Have you tried Electrum-4.1.0 (https://electrum.org/#download)? You can see all transactions history.  There is also a python console that you can use.  Type help() to get all the command available.  If I were you I would start by getaddresshistory('<address>') which will give you a list of dictionary (or a json) and you work your way from there.

Comment: This could help also: https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/blockchaininfo/reference/detailed-bitcoin-data/single-address/get.html